# i am unable to delete user in linux .i created for gitolite installation

Tags: linux, rhel, gitolite

I am unable to delete user in linux RHEL Santiuago 
userdel -r admin

The error message is below 
userdel: /home/admin not owned by admin, not removing.

What to do...?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the simalar process used [by gitlab to reinstall gitolite](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Reinstall-gitolite#2-remove-git-user-with-home-dir), you would see that command is used with sudo:

```
sudo userdel -r admin
```

Even for other cleanup procedures (not related to GitLab), you would use the same sudo prefix. See [this example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/21b742a027f6c2c567d8187c47cb6d99a47c9983/doc/update/4.2-to-5.0.md#9-cleanup)

```
# remove GitLab user from system
sudo userdel -r gitlab
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is an "admin" user try running the command as root